# Building a HTML table in ruby on rails using the content_tag

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, ruby, html-table, content-tag

I'm trying to build a html table in Ruby On Rails with the help of the content_tag method.

Example:

```
@template.content_tag(:tr, @template.content_tag(:td, options[:argument0]))
```

This should render to

```
<tr><td>content of argument0</td></tr>
```

What I need is something like

```
<tr><td>content of argument0</td><td>argument1</td> ... </tr>
```

Can I build this with the same method? How can I pass two content_tags?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `concat` :

```
 @template.content_tag(:tr, 
    @template.content_tag(:td, options[:argument0]).
    concat(@template.content_tag(:td, options[:argument1])).
    concat(@template.content_tag(:td, options[:argument2]))
    # ....
 )
```

Or using a loop - as OP suggested in the comments

```
rows = returning "" do |cells|
   5.times do |i|
     cells.concat @template.content_tag(:td, options["argument#{i}".to_sym]
   end
end
@template.content_tag(:tr,rows)
```